# Get names from Graph API if the ID provided is a non-friend?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a turn-based game and would like to allow players to play games against other users in the database that are not their friends.  Currently I am only storing FB ids from which I am providing a mixed list of friends and non-friends to select from. I have a call to retrieve pictures and names from the FB API but only picture urls are being returned for non-friends.  Is there another way to get names from FB API or do I need to store names in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outline in [Graph API User Section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), you can make a call to the Graph API and get the information (User's name) that you need.

This is an excerpt from that page which is relevant to your requirement:

> You can choose the fields you want returned using the fields query
>   parameter:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name

Modify the above API call like this: 
`https://graph.facebook.com/THE_USER_ID?fields=name, picture`

Also of importance is in the *Fields* table listed on the page linked above. To get the User's Name, `No access_token required`

Now, you haven't tagged the platform you are working on, so I cannot give you the actual code. I work on Android and am not familiar with other platforms. But the Graph API call will essentially remain the same.

Once you have the User's name and Profile Picture, then you can store in your Database if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a JSON object with the name, username, id and photo of any user without an access_token by making a call to:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_OR_ID
```